# First UDP message to a specific remote ip gets lost

Tags: c, sockets, windows-7, network-programming, udp

I am working on a LAN based solution with a "server" that has to control a number of "players"
My protocol of choice is UDP because its easy, I do not need connections, my traffic consists only of short commands from time to time and I want to use a mix of broadcast messages for syncing and single target messages for player individual commands.

Multicast TCP would be an alternative, but its more complicated, not exactly suited for the task and often not well supported by hardware.

Unfortunately I am running into a strange problem:

**The first datagram which is sent to a specific ip using "sendto" is lost.**
Any datagram sent short time afterwards to the same ip is received.
But if i wait some time (a few minutes) the first "sendto" is lost again.

Broadcast datagrams always work.
Local sends (to the same computer) always work.

I presume the operating system or the router/switch has some translation table from IP to MAC addresses which gets forgotten when not being used for some minutes and that unfortunately causes datagrams to be lost.
I could observe that behaviour with different router/switch hardware, so my suspect is the windows networking layer.

I know that UDP is by definition "unreliable" but I cannot believe that this goes so far that even if the physical connection is working and everything is well defined packets can get lost. Then it would be literally worthless.

Technically I am opening an UDP Socket,
bind it to a port and INADRR_ANY.
Then I am using "sendto" and "recvfrom".
I never do a connect - I dont want to because I have several players. As far as I know UDP should work without connect.

My current workaround is that I regularly send dummy datagrams to all specific player ips - that solves the problem but its somehow "unsatisfying"

**Question:** Does anybody know that problem? Where does it come from? How can I solve it?

Edit:

I boiled it down to the following test program:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    SOCKET Sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    SOCKADDR_IN Local = {0};
    Local.sin_family = AF_INET;
    Local.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    Local.sin_port = htons(1234);
    bind(Sock, (SOCKADDR*)&Local, sizeof(Local));
    printf("Press any key to send...\n");
    int Ret, i = 0;
    char Buf[4096];

    SOCKADDR_IN Remote = {0};
    Remote.sin_family = AF_INET;
    Remote.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.12");  // Replace this with a valid LAN IP which is not the hosts one
    Remote.sin_port = htons(1235);

    while(true) {
        _getch();
        sprintf(Buf, "ping %d", ++i);
        printf("Multiple sending \"%s\"\n", Buf);

        // Ret = connect(Sock, (SOCKADDR*)&Remote, sizeof(Remote));
        // if (Ret == SOCKET_ERROR) printf("Connect Error!\n", Buf);
        Ret = sendto(Sock, Buf, strlen(Buf), 0, (SOCKADDR*)&Remote, sizeof(Remote));
        if (Ret != strlen(Buf)) printf("Send Error!\n", Buf);
        Ret = sendto(Sock, Buf, strlen(Buf), 0, (SOCKADDR*)&Remote, sizeof(Remote));
        if (Ret != strlen(Buf)) printf("Send Error!\n", Buf);
        Ret = sendto(Sock, Buf, strlen(Buf), 0, (SOCKADDR*)&Remote, sizeof(Remote));
        if (Ret != strlen(Buf)) printf("Send Error!\n", Buf);
        }
    return 0;
```

The Program opens an UDP Socket, and sends 3 datagrams in a row on every keystroke to a specific IP.
Run that whith wireshark observing your UDP traffic, press a key, wait a while and press a key again.
You do not need a receiver on the remote IP, makes no difference, except you wont get the black marked "not reachable" packets.
This is what you get:

[image: Wireshark Snapshot]

As you can see the first sending initiated a ARP search for the IP. While that search was pending the first 2 of the 3 successive sends were lost.
The second keystroke (after the IP search was complete) properly sent 3 messages.
You may now repeat sending messages and it will work until you wait (about a minute until the adress translation gets lost again) then you will see dropouts again.

**That means: There is no send buffer when sending UDP messages and there are ARP requests pending! All messages get lost except the last one.
Also "sendto" does not block until it successfully delivered, and there is no error return!**

Well, that surprises me and makes me a little bit sad, because it means that I have to live with my current workaround or implement an ACK system that only sends one message at a time and then waits for reply - which would not be easy any more and imply many difficulties.

Comment: You say that if UDP drops packets even in the case of a working network link that it is worthless. I disagree; if you implement ACKs in your protocol, you can make it fairly reliable, but if you want any kind of reliability, you do need to do that.

Comment: "Multicast TCP would be an alternative". No it wouldn't, there is no such thing, so no wonder it isn't "well supported by hardware". Do you mean Multicast *UDP?*

Comment: @icktoofay: I am using UDP because of its simplicity. Indroducing ACKs would greatly increase complexity. I would have to solve questions like "How long to wait before resending a command" and finally the players have the same problem, so what if the command was transmitted but the ACK was not - The server would repeat commands, which would cause problems.

Comment: @OleDittmann: Yes, adding ACKs does increase complexity. However, if you want reliability, you *need* to layer your own mechanisms on top of it (like ACKs) to provide that. It is unreasonable to expect UDP, an *unreliable* protocol, to do that. UDP is not 'worthless', as you said; it just requires more work, but it *does require* that work.

Comment: @OleDittmann: If you do not want to layer your own reliability mechanisms on top of UDP, but you need reliability, you cannot use UDP. Sorry.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm posting this long after it's been answered by others, but it's directly related.

Winsock drops UDP packets if there's no ARP entry for the destination address (or the gateway for the destination).

Thus it's quite likely some of the first UDP packet gets dropped as at that time there's no ARP entry - and unlike most other operating systems, winsock only queues 1 packet while the the ARP request completes.

This is documented [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940021.aspx):

> ARP queues only one outbound IP datagram for a specified destination
>   address while that IP address is being resolved to a MAC address. If a
>   UDP-based application sends multiple IP datagrams to a single
>   destination address without any pauses between them, some of the
>   datagrams may be dropped if there is no ARP cache entry already
>   present. An application can compensate for this by calling the
>   Iphlpapi.dll routine SendArp() to establish an ARP cache entry, before
>   sending the stream of packets.

The same behavior can be observed on [Mac OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man4/arp.4.html) and [FreeBSD](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/4/arp/):

> When an interface requests a mapping for an address not
>   in the cache, ARP queues the message which requires the
>   mapping and broadcasts a message on the associated associated
>   network requesting the address mapping.  If a response is
>   provided, the new mapping is cached and any pending message is
>   transmitted.  ARP will queue at most one packet while waiting
>   for a response to  a mapping request; only the most recently
>   ``transmitted'' packet is kept.

Comment: Thank you, that explains what I found out.

Comment: This one should be the accepted answer, since this exactly describes what's going on here.

Comment: Does it queue per socket or per destination address?

Answer (score 4):

UDP packets are supposed to be buffered on receipt, but a UDP packet (or the ethernet frame holding it) can be dropped at several points on a given machine:

1. network card does not have enough space to accept it,
2. OS network stack does not have enough buffer memory to copy it to,
3. firewall/packet filtering drop-rule match,
4. no application is listening on destination IP and port,
5. receive buffer of the listening application socket is full.

First two points are about too much traffic, which is not likely the case here. Then I trust that point 4. is not applicable and your software is waiting for the data. Point 5. is about your application not processing network data fast enough - also does not seem like the case.

Translation between MAC and IP addresses is done via [Address Resolution Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol). This does not cause packet drop if your network is properly configured.

I would disable Windows firewall and any anti-virus/deep packet inspection software and check what's on the wire with [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org). This will most likely point you into right direction - if you can sniff those first packets on the "sent-to" machines then check local configuration (firewall, etc.); if you don't, then check your network - something in the path is interfering with your traffic.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I will probably do that again on monday. But I already did some research of that kind a few years ago. The problem is haunting me for quite some time and even with different projects, some written in C++ and some with C#. I tried switching of firewalls and anti-virus software. I tried different hardware switches. And I also tried to inspect with wireshark. Cant remember exactly what wireshark said, but I came to no solution. Will try again and do a new analysis.

Comment: "Translation between MAC and IP addresses is done via Address Resolution Protocol. This does not cause packet drop if your network is properly configured." - Seems that it causes drops (See my edit in main post). So, how can I configure that?

Comment: From the wireshark picture you posted, it looks like there's nothing listening for those UDP packets on the destination port on `192.168.1.12` - that's what the ICMP is telling you.

Comment: Yes, thats true. There is no receiver on the remote computer. But that does not matter. Makes no difference if there is one.

Comment: Sniff *on the receiver*! How do you know it's the third packet that gets sent out after ARP completes, and not the first? The packets do get buffered on the NIC input.

Comment: I changed the message on another test, so I saw that it was always the last packet from a series that was sent. I could read the message content in wireshark and had a receiver on the remote computer that displayed them.

Comment: Hmm, what are the times between ARP request and reply? This really should take well under a millisecond on a local network.

Comment: Maybe yes, if you insert a pause after the first of the three consecutive sends then it works. That pause can be very short - didn't test exactly how short.

Comment: ARP translation can cause packets to be dropped, since most ARP implementations (Windows, BSD, OS X) cache at most one packet while an ARP request is in progress and thus only the last packet sent to a host will ever hit the line once an ARP reply is received.

Answer (score 1):

erm ..... Its your computer doing ARP request. When you first start sending, your com does not know the receiver mac address, hence its unable to send any packets. It uses the ip address of the receiver to do an ARP request to get the mac address. During this process, any udp packets you try to send cannot be send out as the destination mac address is still not known.

Once your com receive the mac address it can start sending. However, the mac address will only remain in you com's ARP cache for 2mins (if no further activities is detected between you and the receiver) or 10 mins (full clear of ARP cache, even if connection is active).  That is why you experience this problem every few mins.

Comment: Thats basically what I already found out on my own. The question is, why is that? Is there really no buffer in the networking layer to store messages until they can be send at least for a short time. Or why does does "send" not simply block with a short timeout to wait for the arp request.

Answer (score -3):

> Does anybody know that problem?

The *real* problem is that you assumed that UDP packet sending is reliable. It isn't.

The fact that you lose the first packet with your current network configuration is really a secondary issue. You might be able to fix that, but at any point you are still vulnerable to packet losses.

If packet loss is a problem for you, then you really should use TCP. You can build a reliable protocol on UDP, but unless you have a very good reason to do so, it's no recommended.

Comment: Well I assumed that it would be at least in a LAN under a controlled well defined and not changing environment reliable.

Comment: @Ole Dittmann: what's wrong with TCP? Do you have serious realtime requirements?

Comment: Nothing, its just more effort to program and not well suited for the given task (message oriented, broadcast). And yes I have serious realtime requirements.

Comment: is your input stream oriented, or is it fine if message arrive in random order?

Comment: how is spending time on StackOverflow figuring out what's wrong with this UDP situation less effort than just writing the thing in TCP?

Comment: Well afterwards you are always wiser